# Mantener los 0 a la izquierda

Tags: php

Mi programa me ignora los 0 a la izquierda, ejemplo le pasan 001 y lo toma como 1 y lo necesito todo completo.

Mi codigo va de la siguiente manera

```
function rotate_to_max($n): int {
    echo "El numero inicial es ".$n."\n";
    $vec = array();

    while($n != 0){
        $vec[] = $n%10;
        $n = (integer)($n/10);

    }
    rsort($vec);
    return implode($vec);

}
```

Y al conseguir números como 000001 ignora los 0 y no es lo que quiero.

Que es lo que hace mi codigo me ordena de mayor a menor el numero pasado, entonces 001 me lo toma como 1 y necesito que 001 lo tome como 100 igual con otro numero que pasen, ejemplo: 00145 => 54100 y lo hace es 00145 => 541, entonces 541 != 54100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hazlo como un string, ejemplo:

```
function rotate_to_max($n): int {
    echo "El numero inicial es ".$n[0]."\n";
    $vec = array();
    $i = 0;
    while($n != 0){
        $i++;
        $vec[] = $n[$i] % 10;
        $n = (integer)($n[0] /10);

    }
    rsort($vec);
    return implode($vec);

}
```

Entonces:

```
$val = rotate_to_max("0004");
```

Si estas trabajando con flotantes esto no debería ser así.

Comment: En lo correcto, se debería trabajar con STRING para que se mantenga la numeración de los 0 a la izquierda ya que como int los ceros a la izquierda son nulos.

Answer (score 3):

Creo entender que quieres pasar en tu función números enteros (integer) con `0` liderando.

En `PHP` y creo saber en ningún otro lenguaje, los `0` de la izquierda no se almacenan en la memoria ya que son irrelevantes.

Ejemplo:

```
$num = 000001;

echo $num; // salida: 1 (integer)
echo (string)$num; // salida: "1" (string)
```

No obstante todos los numero liderando con un cero son considerado como [sistema octal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_octal).

Números octales sólo pueden utilizar los dígitos 0-7, al igual en el sistema decimal puedes utilizar 0-9 y 0-1 en números binarias.

Números octal:

```
echo 00;  // 0
echo 01;  // 1
...
echo 06;  // 6
echo 07;  // 7
echo 08;  // Error: no existe
echo 010; // 8
echo 011; // 9
echo 012; // 10
```

Entonces para realizar tu siguiente función `rotate_to_max` tienes que pasar los números como `string` y lo puedes resolver de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
// Podemos declarar el modo estricto
declare(strict_types=1);

// Aquí esperamos un string como valor de entrada
function rotate_to_max(string $string) {

    return "\u{202E}$string";
}

echo rotate_to_max('001005'); // ‮001005
```

[+ info sobre las nuevas características en PHP7](http://php.net/manual/es/migration70.new-features.php)

El compañero Dev.Joel te ha dicho ya que se podría hacer con la función `strrev()`, pero ya que usas las nuevas características de `PHP7` puedes invertir también la cadena con [unicode_escape](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/unicode_escape).

`echo "\u{202E}Reversed text"; // outputs ‮Reversed text`

[Ver Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f998438309633e4193bbb9501fae04d0b4b051bd)

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que ver la función str_pad

`str_pad(1, 3, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)`

Siendo el primer parámetro "1" el valor principal, "3" el número de caracteres y "0" el carácter con el que se llenarán las 3 posiciones y "STR_PAD_LEFT" la posición de los caracteres.

Aquí tienes la documentación oficial:
http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-pad.php

Comment: Esto me hará agregar 3 ceros a un valor cualquiera y necesito es que los 0 se mantengan desde que son pasados en la función. Que el 0000001 sea 0000001 y no 1.

Answer (score 2):

Su función invierte un número. pero los ceros a la izquierda se pierden cuando haces el cast *(Integer)*. Propongo una función para este mismo caso haciendo uso de una sola función en php [strrev($cadena)](http://php.net/manual/es/function.strrev.php) para invertir una cadena.

```
function rotate_to_max($n) {
    echo "El número Inicial es :  ".$n."</br>";
    return strrev($n);
}

echo "El número Final es  : " .rotate_to_max("00001");
```